# How to use RadDateInput for time in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

How to use RadDataInput by time formated in asp.net?

I use this code , but when i get Text of control , get me date and time.

I want get time only

```
<telerik:RadDateInput ID="RadDateInput1"  DateFormat="HH:mm"  runat="server"  >  
</telerik:RadDateInput>
```

Comment: your DateFormat correctly show ?

Comment: yes.  for example,  I input 12:35 but when I  write RadDateInput1.Text , get me 2014-01-27-12-52-00 (dateNow + my input time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code ,

```
  string _time = RadDateInput1.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortTimeString();
```

Comment: tanks, how to set time in this control. For Example I want get time (12:05) from DataBase and set in RadDateInput1.

Comment: You want to save `RadDateInput1`'s time value to database and rebind this value again to this control ? isn't it ?

Comment: tanks. I find my reply :)

Comment: But how to set null value in this control?

Comment: radDateInputTime.SelectedDate = _time != string.Empty ? DateTime.Parse(_time) : "" ;