# How to set time in RadDateInput in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

How to set time in RadDateInput in asp.net?

I want set time in this controls in programming.

I use this code but it is incorrect.

```
RadInputeData.Text = "12:35";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use RadDateInput for time in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379134/how-to-use-raddateinput-for-time-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this approach:**

In HTML:

`<telerik:RadDateInput ID="RadInputeData" runat="server" DisplayDateFormat="HH:mm" Width="125" />`

In Code:

`RadInputeData.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse("12:35");`

Comment: I want set null in RadInputData.

Comment: **Use:**
RadInputeData.SetToNullValue();